# Always Show Overflow ScrollBar

Tags: browser, cross-browser, scroll, scrollbar, overflow

I've noticed that in some situations, in some browsers, my horizontal overflow scrollbar doesn't show up until you START scrolling. That's not good ... users need to know that there is content beyond what's currently being shown.

**Is there a way to make sure that the scrollbar is always shown?**

I've seen this issue on Lion, on a MacBook, in Safari, Chrome.

Comment: Please elaborate. To help you I need to be able to reproduce the problem. What situations are you talking about? Which browsers? Which pages? Can you create a stable example and post it here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there really isn't a way around this without creating your own scrollbar. So I opted to created a custom button navigation.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using Lion, check System Preferences > General > Show scroll bars. This is an OS preference.

The three options are:

1. Automatically based on input device
2. When scrolling
3. Always

This is a "feature" they're trying to carry over from the iOS. That said, you can try something like this:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 7px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}
```

http://www.hardcode.nl/subcategory_2/article_575-force-scrollbars-on-mac-os-lion-webkit.htm

Comment: I have just tried this out on an iPad 2 on iOS 6.1.3 and it doesn't work.

Comment: This isn't for mobile. The OP specifically said he was using Lion, which is OS X 10.7 - a desktop OS.